# How to use overflow:hidden in Angular for only one page?

Tags: html, css, angular, indexing, overflow

I would like to make my window pane unscrollable. If I set my  element to overflow: hidden, I can not scroll on any page, so I tried to do it in the CSS file of the component which I want unscrollable. However, the only way I managed achieve this was adding the unscrollable class name to the  element of index.html.

```
.unscrollable{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, in that case, all windows are unscrollable wherever I navigate on the page.

I tried to solve the problem by adding the following only to the component's CSS file:

```
.unscrollable{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve it? I am very confused by not being able to influence index.html depending on the component, especially since the  tag is there.

Comment: You could have a div that is 100% width and 100vh as height in that particular page that's scrollable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, the parent div of the component's page fills the body, but there is still some scrollable space left - my guess is because of the header reamining scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [angular's Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

You can add overflow hidden css from that component to document's body using this.

import like this

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

then declare in constructor

```
constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2)
```

then use it on ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'overflow', 'hidden');
}
```

this will add overflow hidden to body and page will be unscrollable.

and then make sure to remove overflow hidden from body on that component destroy use ngOnDestroy() to do that

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._renderer.removeStyle(document.body, 'overflow');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It indeed solved my problem, and introduced me to this great feature of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a window sized div non-scrollable like this:

```css
.unscrollable{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem for the same reason as Jacopo Sciampi's solution. Thanks for the contribution anyway!